# Error when trying to access nested objects from API response

Tags: python

I am finding that I keep getting errors when accessing objects that are nest in three other objects.

The following is an example of one of the entities returned when accessing the API:

```
entity {
  id: "000069R"
  trip_update {
    trip {
      trip_id: "064650_R..S"
      route_id: "R"
      start_time: "10:46:30"
      start_date: "20220902"
      nyct_trip_descriptor {
        train_id: "1R 1046+ CTL/95S"
        direction: SOUTH
      }
    }
    stop_time_update {
      stop_id: "G08S"
      arrival {
        time: 1662129990
      }
      departure {
        time: 1662129990
      }
      nyct_stop_time_update {
        scheduled_track: "D1"
        actual_track: "D1"
      }
    }
 }
```

This is my code:

```
import gtfs_realtime_pb2
import urllib.request

trainsets=[
  ['a','c','e'],
  ['b','d','f', 'm'],
  ['g'],
  ['j','z'],
  ['n','q','r', 'w'],
  ['l'],
  ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']
]
set_number=0

# get the train from user and find the corresponding trainset
char = input("What train are you looking for? ")
char = char.lower()
for sets in trainsets:
  if char in sets:
    print('Found it!')
    set_number = trainsets.index(sets)
    
# form string from the values in specified list
desired_trainset= ''.join(trainsets[set_number])

# Communicate with the api
feed = gtfs_realtime_pb2.FeedMessage()
response = urllib.request.Request(f'https://api-endpoint.mta.info/Dataservice/mtagtfsfeeds/nyct%2Fgtfs-{desired_trainset}')
response.add_header("x-api-key", '<API KEY HERE>')
feed.ParseFromString(urllib.request.urlopen(response).read())

# access specific info from the api
for entity in feed.entity:
  if entity.HasField('trip_update'):

    #! ERROR: AttributeError: nyct_trip_descriptor
    print(entity.trip_update.trip.nyct_trip_descriptor.direction)

    #! ERROR: AttributeError: 'google._upb._message.RepeatedCompositeContainer' object has no attribute 'arrival'
    print(entity.trip_update.stop_time_update.arrival.time)
```

The last two print statements are where I keep getting an error. I can access start_time and start_date
or stop_id from the entity just fine, but I keep getting an error when trying to access objects inside other objects.

Using:

Python: 3.10.6

Windows: 11

I've asked a couple of my friends and they don't see the error.
Thank you for helping.

EDIT:

Someone requested to print the entity before the error. This is one of the responses I get back from the data when I do the following code:

```
print(entity.trip_update.trip)

#response I get back

trip_id: "006600_R..N"
route_id: "R"
start_time: "01:06:00"
start_date: "20220903"
nyct_trip_descriptor {
  train_id: "1R 0106 95S/WHL"
}
```

Someone commented that the nyct_trip_descriptor is an optional field, and after rereading the documentation i confirmed that it is optional but I'm not sure how to proceed further and whether or not that is the reason why I'm getting this error. Thank you for helping.

Edit:
I've done the following to return a default value when 'nyct_trip_descriptor' is missing:

```
nyct_trip_descriptor = getattr(entity.trip_update.trip, 'nyct_trip_descriptor', 'not found')
    print(nyct_trip_descriptor)
```

This didn't work since all the entities I got from the API just stated 'not found', but when printing just the entity 'nyct_trip_descriptor' is present as seen in the first code snippet.

Comment: nyct_trip_descriptor is NOT mandatory and can be missing. Thus if you do entity.trip_update.trip.nyct_trip_descriptor, then it will be NOT found.  Try googling on how to safely access a dictionary when an attribute is missing.

Comment: can you print entity before the error so that we can confirm that the keys are surely present?

Comment: the `json` or `dict` is not properly formed...  missing quotations around the keys.  please edit the question to correct.

Comment: @D.L the data in the first code snippet is the raw data I got back. Judging by the quotes on the values such as: id: "000069R", I'm assuming the lack of quotations on the keys is intentional.

Comment: @jose_bacoy hmm... I see what your saying I just reread the documentation, it is optional but shouldn't the error be a key error rather than an attribute error. I feel like what you're saying is related to the error I'm getting but how would i set the value to be a default if the attribute is missing since the data isn't a dict?

Comment: @HarshGupta the first code snippet is one of the entities I got back from the API. I edited the post to include a code snippet of one of the entities I get back when accessing the parent object of nyct_trip_descriptor.